# Snippets with indentation in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I'm trying to create a snippet in Visual Studio Code. This works, but the indentation is missing:

**My snippet :**

```json
"HTML structure": {
    "prefix": "html",
    "body": [
        "<!DOCTYPE html>",
        "<html lang='fr'>",
        "<head>",
            "<meta charset='UTF-8'>",
            "<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>",
            "<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='ie=edge'>",
            "<title>$1</title>",
        "</head>",
        "<body>",
            "$2",
        "</body>",
        "</html>"
    ],
    "description": "Base template for html file"
}
```

**What you see :**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='fr'>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='ie=edge'>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
test
</body>
</html>
```

**What I'd like :**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='fr'>
<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='ie=edge'>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think the more appropriate way is to use `\t` instead of space to maintain document indentation even.

```
"\t<meta charset='UTF-8'>",
```

Comment: Visual Studio Code will convert the tab character into your preferred indentation.

Answer (score 10):

The indentation needs to be inside of the strings, not outside (where it's meaningless), so:

```json
"  <meta charset='UTF-8'>",
```

instead of:

```json
  "<meta charset='UTF-8'>",
```

This works as intended:

```json
"HTML structure": {
    "prefix": "html",
    "body": [
        "<!DOCTYPE html>",
        "<html lang='fr'>",
        "<head>",
        "  <meta charset='UTF-8'>",
        "  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>",
        "  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='ie=edge'>",
        "  <title>$1</title>",
        "</head>",
        "<body>",
        "  $2",
        "</body>",
        "</html>"
    ],
    "description": "Base template for html file"
}
```

Comment: Instead of having indentation as hardcoded in strings, you should better use the escape sequence for tab character "\t".

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this today and wanted to provide a more "robust" answer.

create a file in the .vscode folder called html.code-snippets
please the contents in like i have done here:

```
{
"client-page": {
    "scope": "html",
    "prefix": "sn-client-page",
    "body": [
        "<ion-content>",
        "\t<ion-grid class=\"grid-full-height\">",
        "\t\t<ion-row>",
        "\t\t\t<ion-col>",
        "\t\t\t\t<header>",
        "\t\t\t\t\t<app-client-name></app-client-name>",
        "\t\t\t\t</header>",
        "\t\t\t</ion-col>",
        "\t\t\t<ion-col>",
        "\t\t\t\t<header>title</header>",
        "\t\t\t</ion-col>",
        "\t\t</ion-row>",
        "\t\t<ion-row>",
        "\t\t\t<ion-col>",
        "\t\t\t\t<!---content-->",
        "\t\t\t</ion-col>",
        "\t\t\t<ion-col>",
        "\t\t\t\t<!---content-->",
        "\t\t\t</ion-col>",
        "\t\t</ion-row>",
        "\t</ion-grid>",
        "</ion-content>",
    ]
  }
}
```

I can now start typing "sn" (without the quotes) in a vscode html file and will see the snippet name and hit enter... the output is this!

[image: screenshot of html output]

Please note the using \t each time represents amount of tabs/spaces/ indention. I hope this helps someone. Thanks.